# Error in SQL syntax

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting this error , Not able to make out what is going wrong , please help.

A Database Error Occurred

> Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ')' at line 1

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ud.userid) as id from pr_users_details ud INNER JOIN pr_users u ON ud.userid = u.id WHERE ud.status = '1' AND ()
```

My function looks like this:

```html
 function get_nomination_emailids($functions, $levels, $roles, $locations, $emails)
  {
   
   $SQL.="SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ud.userid) as id from pr_users_details ud INNER JOIN pr_users u ON ud.userid = u.id  WHERE ud.status = '1' ";
   if(count($functions)>0)
   {
    $d = implode(",",$functions);
    $whereand[] = " u.departmentid IN (".$d.") ";
   }
   if(count($levels)>0)
   {
    $d1 = implode(",",$levels);
    $whereand[] = " ud.designation_id IN (".$d1.") ";
   }
   if(count($roles)>0)
   {
    $d2 = implode(",",$roles);
    $whereand[] = " u.userroleid IN (".$d2.") ";
   }
   if(count($locations)>0)
   {
    $d3 = implode(",",$locations);
    $whereand[] = " u.branchid IN (".$d3.") ";
   }
  
   if(count($emails)>0)
   {
    $d4 = implode(",",$emails);
    $whereor[] = " ud.userid IN (".$d4.") ";
   }
   $whr = array();
   
   if(isset($whereand))
   $whr[] = " (".implode(" AND ",$whereand).")  ";
  
   if(isset($whereor))
   $whr[] = " (".implode(" OR ",$whereor).")  ";
   
   
   if(count($whr > 0))
   {
    
    $SQL .= " AND (".implode(" OR ",$whr).") ";
   }
   
   $query = $this->db->query($SQL);
  
   $return =  $query->result_array();
   
   return $return[0]['id'];
   //print_r($return);die;
   
  }
```

Comment: `AND ()` needs to contain something or remove them.

Comment: Btw `count()` returns `1` for every item which is not an array or NULL. So if `$emails` or `$locations` are __FALSE__ count is 1.

Answer (score -1):

AND() remove in your query try this.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ud.userid) as id from pr_users_details ud INNER JOIN pr_users u ON ud.userid = u.id WHERE ud.status = '1'
```